# dockerize container does not able to connect to my sql

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

This is my docker-compose.yaml file

```yaml
version: "3.3"
services:
  redis:
    image: redis:5-alpine
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    network_mode: "host"
    env_file: .env
  backend:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: .
    restart: always
    env_file: .env
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    network_mode: "host"
    depends_on:
      - redis
  celery:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: .
    env_file: .env
    restart: always
    network_mode: "host"
    command: celery -A labb worker -l info -Q default,high_priority,celery_periodic
    depends_on:
      - backend
  celery-beat:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: .
    env_file: .env
    restart: always
    network_mode: "host"
    command: celery -A labb beat -l info --scheduler django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler --pidfile /tmp/celerybeat.pid
    depends_on:
      - backend
  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    env_file: .env
    ports:
      3306:3306
```

```
#0 105.9     connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
#0 105.9   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 121, in Connect
#0 105.9     return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
#0 105.9   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 193, in __init__
#0 105.9     super().__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
#0 105.9 django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (115)")
```

Comment: Why are you disabling networking for most of your containers?  Can you remove the `network_mode:` settings, then use the setup described in [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/)?

Answer (score -1):

Debugging method: you should create a network by typing
`docker network create --driver=bridge full-project-setup-network`
by creating this network you can link all your services to it and even you can inspect the containers' ip by typing `docker network inspect full-project-setup-network`  , add networks section in each service  (networks:
- full-project-setup-network) inside docker-compose file and then type `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up --build` after building the imagesand launching the containers please enter `docker exec -it <pythoncontainer> /bin/sh` grap the ip of mysql container by inspecting `full-project-setup-network` and type `ping mysql_ip_container` inside your python container.

Comment: You never need the Docker-internal IP addresses and there's never a need to look them up.  Also consider that the addresses can change as containers are destroyed and recreated.

Comment: I know he needs only the service name.  I told him my idea to make sure that python container can talk to mysql container by inspecting the network.